# URL API design considerations and REST action

Tags: rest, api, api-design

We have a cart and cart has line items, now line items can be products, discount coupons, rewards and promotions. I am looking for some inputs in design consideration here. The backend is in Ruby on Rails.

```
for products I have already designed the URL to be 
post: cart/line_items to create a line item for product
put: cart/line_items/:id to update the quantity
delete: cart/line_items/:id to remove the product
```

Now for Adding of samples and removing of samples, I am thinking of going this way.

```
get: cart/line_items/samples to get all the samples.
post: cart/line_items/samples to create a line item for sample
delete: cart/line_items/samples/:id to remove that sample from the cart
```

for discount coupon, rewards and promotions I am thinking of similar design. It would be great if experts can give me some inputs here.

Comment: why `samples` is a sub-resource of `line_items` and `products` is not ? Seems strange...

Comment: @AilurusFulgens it was already implemented this way, so if we are going to add samples and other resource `cart/line_items/samples` then may be I would change the implementation for products also, but this is still under consideration so I am looking for input if I should implement it this way or is there a better implementation.

Comment: Where are the cart IDs in those URLs? I would do something like `post: /cart/:id/line_items'. Similar for all the other URLs. Basically as describes in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) under 'nested resources'. Also it is rather unclear what role exactly the 'samples' play here. Why do they need to be below line_items? Could you maybe show your model structure?

Comment: @thorsten müller Cart is a singular resource. Samples, discount coupons, rewards belongs to a line item, so samples gets added to the cart as a line item. This was implemented quite a long time back

Comment: There is another thing how about doing all these actions on cart/line_items and in the controller based on the params like [:product_id], [:samples_id] create line items?

Comment: Thinking of using factory pattern here @thorstenmüller to create line items based on different params

Comment: Using only `line_items` was somewhat my first thought. Would depend on how different those things are from each other. An alternative would be to omit the `line_items` part in the URL (similar to shallow routing in the guide) and while keeping the `samples` controller using routes like `/cart/samples/:id`. To show the whole cart you still could have `get: /cart/line_items` maybe. Would somewhat depend on who consumes this API, potentially a bit confusing to some people. With the params approach you would somewhat run the risk to have a swiss army knife controller.

Comment: @thorstenmüller thanks what you are suggesting is really a valid concern regarding creating a factory. One controller will be tightly coupled with lots of other actions, would run in to a lot of if conditions.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the Item-collection pair

`/collection/{item}/collection/{item}`

If you think on these lines, you will design your api as follows.

`/cart/12041/line_item/3192/sample/31314`

As you can see, each uri contains its identifier(item) before another collection is added.

If you say, cart will not have any *item id*, then it becomes

`/cart_line_item/3192/sample/31314` instead.

All the HTTP verbs will work on this URI convention.